# How to iterate trough JSON list in python and insert into PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, postgresql, list

I am a bit stuck and the solutions I can think of will end in spaghetti code.

I am having the following JSON, I create an object of it in python 3 and I have to insert the values into PostgreSQL.

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "country": "DE",
    "time": "21-Oct-2019 (09:58:01.694763)",
    "toCurrency": ["EUR", "USD", "GBP"],
    "fromCurrency": ["DKK", "DKK", "DKK"],
    "buyMargin": ["1.2800", "1.2800", "2.0000"],
    "sellMargin": ["1.2800", "1.2800", "2.0000"],
    "unit": "M100" 
}
```

I am getting the exception: `can only concatenate str (not "list") to str`

- How can I iterate through those lists in Python and insert one value at a time?

At the same time the other values of 'name', 'country', 'time' should be inserted every time.

Currently I can insert this JSON:

```
{
"name": "test",
"country": "DE",
"time": "21-Oct-2019 (09:58:01.694763)",
"toCurrency": "EUR",
"fromCurrency": "DKK",
"buyMargin": "1.2800",
"sellMargin": "1.2800",
"unit": "M100" 
}
```

Comment: are the values going to be inserted in a `json` column or they have to be parsed and inserted in 8 different columns?

Comment: They will be inserted in 8 different columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your data to a dataframe using pandas. Then using `sqlalchemy`, store this dataframe as a table in PostGre.

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
d1 = {
    "name": "test",
    "country": "DE",
    "time": "21-Oct-2019 (09:58:01.694763)",
    "toCurrency": ["EUR", "USD", "GBP"],
    "fromCurrency": ["DKK", "DKK", "DKK"],
    "buyMargin": ["1.2800", "1.2800", "2.0000"],
    "sellMargin": ["1.2800", "1.2800", "2.0000"],
    "unit": "M100" 
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
engine = create_engine(
        'postgresql://username:password@host:port/database')
df1.to_sql(tablename, engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Your Dataframe will look as follows. And will similarly be stored as a table in PostGre

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this solution! It is really clean and structured. Can I specify primary keys for the table in this way?

Comment: You can do that from postgres itself, after you create the table.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correct and your `toCurrency`, `fromCurrency`, `buyMargin` and `sellMargin` have equal number of elements which they should, the following should work gor you:

```
j = {
    "name": "test",
    "country": "DE",
    "time": "21-Oct-2019 (09:58:01.694763)",
    "toCurrency": ["EUR", "USD", "GBP"],
    "fromCurrency": ["DKK", "DKK", "DKK"],
    "buyMargin": ["1.2800", "1.2800", "2.0000"],
    "sellMargin": ["1.2800", "1.2800", "2.0000"],
    "unit": "M100"
}

for idx, val in enumerate(j['toCurrency']):
    print(j['toCurrency'][idx], j['fromCurrency'][idx], j['buyMargin'][idx], j['sellMargin'][idx])
```

So your insert statement should be in the position of the print and your columns should be accordingly.